# How to do variable0 = 0 ... variable9 = 9 in Python

Tags: python

I have a simple question of beginner.

How to make this code work :

```
variable0 = 0

...
variable9 = 9
```

I tried :

```
for j in range(9):
    variable"{}".format(j) = j
```

and others similar things with eval() and exec() functions.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You don't *want* lots of similarly named variables like this; use a list instead: `variable = list(range(10))`.

Comment: Why do you need this? Please checkout [what is an XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - it seems unlikely this is your needed solution.

Comment: Dynamically creating variables is indeed possible in Python, but you probably do not want that. The good question here is *why should we use dynamic variables instead of lists, arrays or dictionaries*. Unless you can give an acceptable answer to that question, I will only say here: stick to a Python container.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use a list instead, together with list comprehension:

```
variable = [i for i in range(10)]
```

Then you could use `variable[0]` for your "variable0", etc.

---

Or, as mentioned in a few comments

```
variable = list(range(10))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to do this you can do:

```
for j in range(9):
    exec("variable{} = j".format(j))
```

But as others have said, you probably shouldn't.

Comment: To be honest this is the actual answer, though unlikely what OP really needs.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't! @DirtyBit SO isn't about just giving the exact answer OP wants, it's also about guiding them to what the *should* do.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Of course it is about guiding them to the right approach, but sometimes people need specific behaviour. For example changing variable names dynmically if he/she needs 10 different variables while assigning values and it is impossible to do it with the list approach. I think it is better to give the exact answer if possible but to **advise** to read or try some different approach or to tell that this approach is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using numbers, use a list:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
```

or

```
items = range(10)
```

then you can look up `items[0]`, `items[2]`, etc

If you want to use something else to identify items, use a dictionary:

```
items = {
    1: 1,
    2: 2,
    'foo': 'bar'
    ...
}
```

You can look up with `items[0]`, `items['foo']`, etc

You can also use list comprehension or dictionary comprehension to define your data structures, e.g.

```
items = {i: i for i in range(10)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of a dictionary is better suited for this task:

```
d = {"variable{}".format(i): i for i in range(10)}

print(d['variable0']) # ==> 0
print(d['variable5']) # ==> 5
print(d['variable9']) # ==> 9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really need this specific behaviour (changing variable names on the fly) there is a way to acomplish it. I don't recommend this solution, since there are more intuitive ones and this approach is not a very good design. Here it is:

```
l = locals()
counter = 0;
for i in range(9):
   l["variable" + str(counter)] = i
   counter += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't really recommend this but you could assign the globals() or locals() dictionaries depending on whether you're doing this at the module level or within a function.

```
for i in range(10): globals()[f'variable{i}'] = 0

def myfunc():
    for i in range(10): locals()[f'variable{i}'] = 0
```